# Google Driving Directions To Nearest Road

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm looking to create driving directions between two points where one or both of the points does not have a road directly to it, but near it.

For example if you use the DirectionsService try to create a drive line between Moab, UT and Zion National Park, UT you will get back Zero_Results since there is no road to the CENTER (the lat, lng returned by google) of Zion Nation Park. If you do the same on google.com/maps you will see a drive line from Moab to the Zion National Park's East Entrance and a walk to the center of the park (where the pin is placed). How did they determine where to drive to for Zion National Park?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  For your question, what sorts of approaches/algorithms have you tried?  Folks here are glad to help, but we don't necessarily want to do the research/coding for you.  You'll get great responses if you show what research/approaches you've tried already, etc.

Comment: I don't want code. I've written a ton to try and figure this out. I'm more looking for an idea of how to do this. As far as I can tell there is no way in the API to tell the DirectionsService to find the closest road when creating a Drive. This means that a custom solution is needed. I tried using the nearby seach with a decent radius, but the problem there is you don't actually know which end point is causing ZERO_RESULTS to be returned. I'm just trying to figure out if there is a request option I missed or if anyone has a good idea as to how to go about this. No code is required for that.

Answer (score 2):

If you [reverse geocode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#ReverseGeocoding) the coordinates returned by the geocoder for Zion National Park (37.2982022,-113.0263005), the first result will be the nearest location on the road.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maunjbf3/2/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var start = "Moab, UT";
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  geocodeAddress("Zion National Park", start);
}

function geocodeAddress(address, start) {
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': address
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      geocoder.geocode({
        'location': results[0].geometry.location
      }, function(results, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          calculateAndDisplayRoute(start, results[0].geometry.location)
        } else {
          window.alert('Reverse Geocode failed due to: ' + status);
        }
      });
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}

function calculateAndDisplayRoute(start, end) {
  directionsService.route({
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    } else {
      window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```